# What regulation allows airlines to require flight attendants to work up to 20 hours?

Tags: faa-regulations, airline-operations, flight-attendant

What regulation can a Part 121 airline use to bypass the rest requirements for flight attendants?

Our airline has been working flight attendants for up to 20 hours using the term "irregular operations". For example: "oops, the pilot is late"; "oops, there's bad weather"; "oh, you're at your home but we still need you to make that last leg even though you will be over your hours by 3 hrs". What regulation allows this?

Comment: The question in the header and the one in the body are actually different questions with different answers. 121.467(b)(14) allows for extending duty time “due to circumstances beyond the control of the certificate holder.” But bypassing rest requirements is not allowed. [This legal interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/cabin_safety/regs/legal/media/FellInterp.pdf) from 2005 refers to a “long held FAA position that circumstances beyond the control of the certificate holder permit exceeding duty period limitations but does not permit reducing required rest periods.”